# Pomodoro timer for linux

Tags: linux, productivity

Is there good Pomodoro **desktop** timer for Linux without a lot of dependencies.

I know about [pomodairo](https://code.google.com/p/pomodairo/), but it's made with Adobe Air, which I don't want on my Linux (even if it exists for Linux).

Comment: I used to run `i3` and `bwpwm`, but recently I have been using `gnome`. I feel like I am more productive when I am in `gnome` rather than a tiling wm -- mostly when I am working with `blender`, `gimp`, or other applications that are heavily reliant on the mouse rather than `vim` or other terminal applications. I have recently discovered `gnome-shell-pomodoro-git` (A.U.R.), which can be found here https://github.com/codito/gnome-pomodoro for non-arch users. I think it looks very nice: http://imgur.com/a/aKKRF

Answer (score 59):

If you're into minimalistic approaches, I'd suggest one I found [here](http://magnatecha.com/very-simple-pomodoro-timer-for-a-terminal/), that uses the Terminal:

```
sleep 1500 && notify-send "break"
```

Where `1500` stands for "1500 seconds", which is equivalent to 25 minutes. In order to take breaks, you should issue the following:

```
sleep 300 && notify-send "back to work"  # a short, 5-minute break
sleep 900 && notify-send "back to work"  # a long, 15-minute break
```

Of course, you can also issue the whole thing at once, like this:

```
sleep 1500 && notify-send "break"; sleep 300 && notify-send "back to work"
sleep 1500 && notify-send "break"; sleep 300 && notify-send "back to work"
sleep 1500 && notify-send "break"; sleep 300 && notify-send "back to work"
sleep 1500 && notify-send "break"; sleep 900 && notify-send "back to work"
```

This approach uses visual and silent notifications, which I find ideal, but I'm sure you can tweak it to give you a beep instead of a notification, in case you prefer.

Of course, you can also go crazy and add subtitles, icons, and different urgency levels. You can run `man notify-send` to see the options or check out [this nice article](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/12/ubuntu-notify-send/) that I've found to be quite helpful. I've also published software on GitHub that does this, feel free to fork or contribute to the [upstream repo](https://github.com/wleoncio/pomodoro).

You may also use zenity to have a more sticky notification. For example:

```
sleep 1500 && zenity --warning --text="25 minutes passed"
```

The dialog won't close until you explicitly push the OK button. Run `man zenity` for more information.

Comment: This is awesome. On breaks I have it notify every minute with remaining minutes. Thanks!

Comment: Based on this answer, I created a [simple script](https://gist.github.com/jameswpm/2833c89b18fc3f571985779cbee0a2b8) that worked fine in Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm using as a minimalist pomodoro timer. Awesome tips.

Comment: If you already sent the command to run in the background and want to check how long you have suffered so far: `jobs -l` to get the process id PID, and then `ps -o etime -p PID`

Comment: @James: you just counter-improved the minimalistic approach :)

Answer (score 12):

I am using [Flowkeeper](http://flowkeeper.org/) which needs Java.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Consider Workrave, as it has software packages (eg. an Ubuntu package, `workrave`) available.  It appears to be mostly written in C++.

See this [blog post on pomodoro with Workrave](http://computersandbuildings.com/pomodoro-workrave-well-being/).

I also notice that there's an "idle" feature (which is probably not helpful for practicing pomodoro) built into Workrave.  Also see this [blog post on adjusting idle time](http://blog.lifepattern.org/2013/02/20/workrave-tuning/).

Comment: Over the last few days I've been using [Resto](http://just-code.org/applications/resto/), since running Pop!_OS does not really provide a place for the Workrave system tray GUI.  So far it's pretty nice (no Debian/Ubuntu package available though, alas)!

Answer (score 4):

Here is one from Softpedia (at your own risk): http://linux.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/Pomodoro-Timer-55822.shtml

[image]

I know it is not based on the Pomodoro method...

> "Timer Applet: Available in most Linux systems' repositories, this unobtrusive applet works great for those who like to work in timed bursts. Start the timer as either a running clock or set it to alert you at a custom interval of time."

From: http://lifehacker.com/5048628/make-your-linux-desktop-more-productive (part-way down the page)

[image]

Comment: The Timer Applet's presets would work really well for the Pomodoro method.

Answer (score 3):

I have been using this other software called [Tomate](https://launchpad.net/tomate) that is pretty decent. It is very simple to install and has all of the Pomodoro Technique timers already preset (25,5,15). I particularly like the grey Tomate icon in the systray that gradually becomes red clockwise as the timer progresses. It gives you a sense of how much time has elapsed without the actual stress of watching the clock ticking.

Comment: This is great - simple, functional, doesn't need Java... ;) The repo has moved to https://github.com/eliostvs/tomate-gtk