# Launching gnome-shell-timer in Unity?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, productivity, ubuntu-unity, timer

I'd like to have a **countdown timer** in my taskbar on an Ubuntu 12.04 machine with Unity 2D. My use case is primarily time management, for example "countdown from 30 minutes, and I'll take a break when the timer finishes."

I installed [gnome-shell-timer](https://github.com/olebowle/gnome-shell-timer) by doing `sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-timer`. However, I'm not sure how to *launch* the gnome-shell-timer application. Here's what I've tried:

- I typed `gnome-shell-timer` on the command line, but it says `command not found`.
- I restarted the computer, hoping that the timer would appear in the taskbar. No such luck, though.

**I've installed gnome-shell-timer. How do I launch it?**

---

While we're on this topic, here's my survey of Linux timer applications that I've tried recently:

- [pomodoro timer](http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/Pomodoro-Timer-Download-55822.html) installs easily, and it's effective. BUT, it runs in its own window instead of in the taskbar. Also, it only allows you to choose "5, 15, or 25 minutes" instead of selecting whatever amount of time you want.
- [kteatime](http://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.kde.org/applications/games/kteatime/&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHhJqWhzrOcqaOG47vuGqdBOPtdCA) runs in the taskbar. It installs with apt-get, and it can be launched with `kteatime &`. BUT, it doesn't actually display a countdown, and it sometimes loses my settings when I restart it.
- I used to use [timer-applet](https://launchpad.net/timer-applet) on an earlier Ubuntu version (perhaps 10.04), perhaps running some version of Gnome desktop.  However, when I try to install timer-applet on my current machine, there are a bunch of "uninstallable" dependencies like `python-gnome2-desktop`.
- [gnome-shell-pomodoro](https://github.com/codito/gnome-shell-pomodoro) (not to be confused with [pomodoro timer](http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/Pomodoro-Timer-Download-55822.html)) runs in the taskbar, and it looks great in [pictures](https://a248.e.akamai.net/camo.github.com/6a075ca33a2f8ff25da4871c9d9fc0fe26cd849b/687474703a2f2f6b616d696c707275736b6f2e6f72672f66696c65732f676e6f6d652d7368656c6c2d706f6d6f646f726f2d657874656e73696f6e2e706e67). Based on the dependency errors I get when trying to apt-get install, gnome-shell-pomodoro is a wrapper around timer-applet.

---

Thanks to [this SuperUser thread](https://superuser.com/questions/224265/pomodoro-timer-for-linux) for introducing me to some of these apps.

Comment: +1 for the survey. Decent apps for this are few. Tomighty [Java] is one you might want to have a look at: https://github.com/ccidral/tomighty

Answer (score 5):

Tomate seems to have everything you want, it's fairly simply and focused on pomodoros, but you can choose the lengths of the work and break times, and you can get it to hide into the taskbar:
https://launchpad.net/tomate

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stvs/tomate
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tomate
```

(By the way, this info was taken from here: https://askubuntu.com/a/190675/18478.)

Comment: Just installed, seems great. Only thing missing is the timer counting down in the panel/taskbar (what is the name of that thing in Unity?) when in hidden state. Currently only shows a tomato symbol with a clock-like completion overlay.

Comment: The icon in the panel/taskbar is called an indicator on unity. You've got a lot of indicators available by the way : https://itsfoss.com/best-indicator-applets-ubuntu/

Answer (score 2):

There is an explanation on how to activate the extension in the source readme file (just scroll down to "Enable the extension using gnome-tweak-tool ..." at https://github.com/olebowle/gnome-shell-timer

Unfortunately, I dont't understand how to use the gsettings in my terminal.  Would like to get it to work, too :)

Answer (score 2):

There is also [Alarm Clock](http://alarm-clock.pseudoberries.com/)

```
sudo apt-get install alarm-clock-applet
alarm-clock-applet &
```

The look of the panel:

[image: picture of panel]

And configuring an alarm/timer..

[image]

It seems to do everything I need it to.

Comment: 404 on that link now

Comment: Just updated the URL...

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add the applet to the panel. I am not running gnome at the moment but it should be something like Right Click on the panel => "Add applet to panel" or "Panel properties" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

What about kalarm? It has a high level of customizability, and I think you can show time as a tooltip at least.

Comment: The OP may not want to install all of `kalarm`'s dependencies (kdelibs is a big package).

Comment: It installed well on my Ubuntu 12.10 w/Unity, but I got a bug similar to [this](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=293208).

Comment: I am just saying that some people would rather install apps that use the current desktop's libraries, instead of having to install the libraries for another desktop.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled quite a bit with getting it running too. Open the gnome-tweak-tool (run from terminal or use the 'advanced option' through gnome).

Go to Shell Extensions, and click on Timer Extension (don't expect it to be at the bottom).

It will now appear up top in gnome, near the volume controller, hope this will help others struggling to get the program running.

Comment: The OP was asking for Unity though... ?